# Recursive Java function with exceptions

Tags: java, recursion

I have a table of with ids & their neighbors and need to create a recursive function that finds all possible paths from the start id to the end id **without crossing the the same points twice**. Lets assume the start id is 1 and the end id is 3. The only possible complete paths are (1,2,3) & (1,5,3)

```
{1 | 2,5}
{2 | 1,3,4,5}
{3 | 2,5}
{4 | 2}
{5 | 1,2,3}
```

Current Code (via @Jeffrey Phillips Freeman)

```
List<Integer> searchHops(int from, int to, List<Integer> seen) {
    seen.add(from);

    if (from == to)
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(from));

    for (int neighbor : getNeighbors(from))

        if (!seen.contains(neighbor)) {
            List<Integer> result = searchHops(neighbor, to, seen);

            if (result != null) {
                result.add(0, from);
                return result;
            }
        }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi royjr, did you give it a go yourself? If so, where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: @notyou Thanks for the quick reply! The problem is, without ignoring the previously visited neighbors, we get stuck in an infinite loop. Eg. 1,2,1,2... whereas if we disregarded the previously visited neighbors, we would get 1,2,3

Comment: You should probably delete this question, start again, provide the extra information as in your comment above, and also provide your code attempt (see: [mcve]) and point at your *specific* problem and the community will be better placed to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following should do the trick. I will leave it to you to implement the getNeighbors method. You should also call the method with seen being an empty ArrayList

```
private List<Integer> searchHops(int from, int to, List<Integer> seen) {
  seen.add(from);
  if( from == to )
    return new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(from));
  for(int neighbor : getNeighbors(from) )
    if( !seen.contains(neighbor) ) {
      List<Integer> result = searchHops(neighbor, to, seen);
      if(result != null) {
        result.add(0, from);
        return result;
      }
    }
  return null;
}

//actual entry point
public List<Integer> searchHops(int from, int to) {
    return searchHops(from, to, new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
```

Comment: I think that you forgot a parameter in the recursive call searchHops(neighbor, to);

Comment: @Dvorog oops thanks, good catch. I was winging it. I have updated it.

Comment: Missing `)` in 2nd if-statement.

Comment: @Dvorog Amazing! I was able to get one successful list of points, but how do I go about getting all possible lists and pushing them into an arraylist to finally select the shortest path? I added my current code above.

Comment: @royjrI think you meant to direct that at me. That wasnt what you asked for originally.  That problem is a bit more complicated but only requires a small modification to this answer.

Comment: @royjr since you already got a negative score why not accept my answer, close the question, and ask a new one properly worded (link me there and I'll even answer it for you).

Comment: @royjr all you did was copy and paste my answer into your question, then changed the question to make it look like you did some work. Put in a little effort please.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman Good assumption! Basically I'm trying to find the shortest path in distance, not by number of points. So my idea was to find all the possible paths, store them into an ArrayList and take it from there.

Comment: @royjr seriously close this question and let me help you right it the best way. your approach to finding the shortest path itself is wrong.. What I provided is called a depth-first-search. What you want is a breadth-first-search. which will always return the shortest path.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman, Sorry about that, but thats the actual code that worked on my end. We'll start a new thread, much appreciated.

Comment: @royjr Ask your question right, say that your looking for the shortest path, and show the code you currently have (i guess its my code so credit me at least so it doesnt look like your passing the work off as your own).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170004/discussion-between-royjr-and-jeffrey-phillips-freeman).